@media (orientation) does not work on Safari mobile
I cannot get @media (orientation) working on mobile Safari.
iOS 15.8.3, iPhone SE
The code I have written works the way it should on Chrome and Firefox, tested on Windows/Linux/OSX and Android. Also tested on Safari on OSX where it works the way it should.
If I skip using the @media query, that is just use normal height and font-size tags everything works but then I have no chance to know if the phone is in portrait or landscape mode.
The users for the code, when I get it right, will have a mixture of iOS and Android devices so I must be able to find out if it is portrait/landscape on various both iOS and Android devices
I tried to write the @media tag in many different ways but I cannot get it to work.


.jma_mobile_html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.jma_mobile_body {
  min-height: 100dvh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.jma_mobile_title_center {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #AAAAAA;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  @media (orientation: portrait) {
    height:8dvh;
    font-size: 4dvh;
  }
  @media (orientation: landscape) {
    height: 10dvh;
    font-size: 5dvh;
  }
  overflow:hidden;
}

.jma_mobile_title_sub_center {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #AAAAAA;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  @media (orientation: portrait) {
    font-size:1.5dvh;
  }
  @media (orientation: landscape) {
    font-size: 2dvh;
  }
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.jma_mobile_page {
  @media (orientation: portrait) {
    height:87dvh;
    font-size: 3dvh;
  }
  @media (orientation: landscape) {
    height: 80dvh;
    font-size: 5dvh;
  }
  background: #EEEEEE;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  overflow:auto;
}

.jma_mobile_footer {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #AAAAAA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  @media (orientation: portrait) {
    height:5dvh;
    font-size: 2.5dvh;
  }
  @media (orientation: landscape) {
    height: 10dvh;
    font-size: 6dvh;
  }
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="jma_mobile_html">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>TEST</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="car.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="jma_mobile_body">
  <div class="jma_mobile_title_center">MAIN TITLE
    <div class="jma_mobile_title_sub_center">Text as subtextline</div>
  </div>
  <div class="jma_mobile_page">
  </div>
  <div class="jma_mobile_footer">TEST - 2024-09-06</div>
</body>

</html>




I have found no official documentation yet that specifically states that media queries can be nested inside other elements. I only found documentation that allows you to nest media queries within each other if they start from the root! While it might work on other browsers, it might solely because of the error correction handling. Fix your media queries and see if to is working then.

See https://caniuse.com/?search=nesting Safari IOS did not fully support nesting in CSS until 17.2 so de-nesting as @tacoshy recommends should help.

Yes, reworked the css file and now it works.
I did not know about caniuse.com - great help.
